# Mudança feita em um dicionário que está em uma lista de listas acaba refletindo em todas as outras sub-listas

Tags: python, lista, matriz, dicionário

Estou tentando fazer uma matriz de listas para colocar um dicionário em cada célula (adicionei mais uma porque a matriz tem a célula 0)

```
ncolunas = 1
nlinhas = 1

mc = [{'column': 0, 'row': 0}] * (ncolunas + 1)
matrizposi = [mc] * (nlinhas + 1)
```

Cada célula recebe um 'column' e um 'row'

```
[[{'column': 0, 'row': 0}, {'column': 0, 'row': 0}], [{'column': 0, 'row': 0}, {'column': 0, 'row': 0}]]
```

Tentei acessar a primeira célula dessa maneira:

```
matrizposi[0][0]['column'] = 1
matrizposi[0][0]['row'] = 1
```

Mas ela altera o valor de todas as células

```
[[{'column': 1, 'row': 1}, {'column': 1, 'row': 1}], [{'column': 1, 'row': 1}, {'column': 1, 'row': 1}]]
```

Quero acessar a primeira célula e alterar o valor do 'column' e do 'row' dessa célula sem prejudicar as outras.

O ideal seria isso:

```
[[{'column': 1, 'row': 1}, {'column': 0, 'row': 0}], [{'column': 0, 'row': 0}, {'column': 0, 'row': 0}]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente, ao fazer algo como `[ x ] * 3`, o resultado é `[ x, x, x ]`, ou seja, uma lista com 3 referências ao mesmo objeto `x`.

Podemos conferir se é o mesmo imprimindo seus id's:

```py
for linha in matrizposi:
    print('linha:', id(linha))
    for dic in linha:
        print('dic:', id(dic))
```

O resultado será algo assim:

```
linha: 140052455590144
dic: 140052456408576
dic: 140052456408576
linha: 140052455590144
dic: 140052456408576
dic: 140052456408576
```

Os números podem variar a cada execução, mas veja que todas as linhas têm o mesmo `id`, assim como todos os dicionários também. Isso indica que a matriz possui duas referências para a mesma lista, que por sua vez possui duas referências para o mesmo dicionário. Por isso que ao mudar o dicionário de uma posição, isso acaba afetando todas.

Se quer criar um novo dicionário a cada iteração, tem que fazê-lo explicitamente:

```py
matrizposi = []
for _ in range(nlinhas + 1):
    linha = []
    for _ in range(ncolunas + 1):
        linha.append({'column': 0, 'row': 0})
    matrizposi.append(linha)
```

Ou ainda, usando [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
matrizposi = [ [ {'column': 0, 'row': 0} for _ in range(ncolunas + 1) ] for _ in range(nlinhas + 1) ]
```